# What is the reason for this behaviour in my flexed div?

Tags: css

I'm currently working on a sign-up page for a website using Vue and Tailwind(I'm not looking for a tailwind based answer specifically, anything is fine).
[This is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td2Vp.png)

This is the code for the page (I've removed v-model and props for easier read)

```
<template>
    <div class="h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
        <form class="w-3/5 font-mono" action="">
            <InputFieldText1/>
            <InputFieldText1/>
            <button type="button" @click="toggleShow" class="absolute -translate-y-[3.125rem]  right-0 cursor-help showhide">
                <span v-if="passwordState === 'password'"><ShowIcon class="w-6 h-6"/></span>
                <span v-else><HideIcon class="w-6 h-6"/></span>
            </button>
            <InputFieldText1/>
            <button type="button" @click="toggleShowRepeat" class="absolute -translate-y-[3.125rem]  right-0 cursor-help showhide">
                <span v-if="passwordRepeatState === 'password'"><ShowIcon class="w-6 h-6"/></span>
                <span v-else><HideIcon class="w-6 h-6"/></span>
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="font-normal text-base float-right btn">Sign-up<NextIcon class="w-4 h-4 inline ml-1 nexticon"/></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.nexticon{
    transition: margin-right 250ms;
}
.btn:hover .nexticon{
    margin-right: -0.25rem;
}
</style>
```

And this is the code for `InputFieldText1` (Again removed the  functional bit for easier read)

```
<template>
    <div class="relative w-full border-b-2 border-current mt-5 ml-auto mr-auto mb-5 field">
        
        <input class="outline-none border-none overflow-hidden m-0 w-full p-1 pl-0 bg-transparent input" 
        "/>
        
        <label class="-z-10 absolute w-full -translate-x-full translate-y-1 text-lg label" :for="inputid"></label>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.field::after{
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background: whitesmoke;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: 0%;
    transition: transform 500ms ease;
    top: 2px;
}
.field:focus-within{
    border-color: transparent;
}
.field:focus-within::after{
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
.label{
    transform-origin: 0%;
    transition: transform 400ms;
}
.field:focus-within .label, .input:not(:placeholder-shown) + .label{
    transform: scale(0.8) translateY(-1.5rem) translateX(-125%);
}
</style>
```

This is working almost perfectly, that is exactly how I want those things to look, but now I want to add a 'Already a user? Login' link below the form.

However, when I try to put it below the form,

```
<div class="h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
        <form class="w-3/5 font-mono" action="">
            
        </form>
        <a>Already a user? Login</a>
    </div>
```

[This happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhbSz.png).
Understandable because its flexing.

Then I tried to put the whole thing in a div,

```
<div class="h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
        <div>
        <form class="w-3/5 font-mono" action="">
           
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[And this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99jTz.png).

Giving the div `width 100%`,

```
<div class="h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
        <div class="w-full">
        <form class="w-3/5 font-mono" action="">
          
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Did not work either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TZG5.png).

`Flex basis 100%` on the form and the Link in all combinations did not work either.

Any help on why this happens and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated. I am aware I can use absolute positioning, however I'm trying to see if there's another way because I'll need to put in stuff like "Signup with google" and It'll be a pain to position them all across viewports.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably you only set `display:flex` so by default it is `flex-direction:row`, try to set `flex direction:column`

Comment: Could you please provide CSS for classes h-screen and flex? One of them is causing it, most likely the flex one, because you have not set flex-direction, or have it set on row

Comment: h-screen is `height:100vh` and flex is `display:flex`

Comment: Flex direction did work! Thank you so much!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).